# Construct a SOAP Request to a WebService using Axis2 Library in Java?

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I need to be able to construct a SOAP request using Apache Axis2 and provide the IP address and user agent in the SOAP header to the webservice. Is there a code sample that describes how to do that?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Best wishes
Ruchi Kaur.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to get the WSDL of the service you are trying to call, and then use the [wsdl2java tool](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_3/userguide-creatingclients.html#generating) to generate a client for you.

If you want to code it yourself, you can use the Axis2 API...an example can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205240/axis2-web-service-client-generation-types-without-modifying-the-client/206188).